# How to reuse a function for multiple select options that only use a single event handler in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a small player simulator. You select a team and that team's players become available. You select a player and that player's stats become available.

I'm trying to reuse a single onChange handler for each of the select elements.

In my initial code I'm having to use a seperate player stats function for each player on the team. (homePlayer1Stats and homePlayer2Stats in the example below) Which would give me 11 stats functions for both home and away team. Can you tell me how to turn homePlayer1 homePlayer2 etc. into homePlayer(i) so I can use a single stats function?

I've included the App, and the team and player select components here fore completeness.

```
const intialValues = {
  home: 'Choose team',
  away: 'Choose team',
  homePlayer1: 'Choose Opener',
  homePlayer2: 'Choose Opener',
  awayPlayer1: 'Choose Opener'
};

function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(intialValues);
    
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
          ...values,
          [name]: value,
      });
  };
  
  function homePlayerArray() {
    const filteredArray = statsFile.filter(element => {
      return element.Country === values.home
    })
    const sortedArray = filteredArray.sort((a,b) => (a.Player > b.Player) ? 1 : ((b.Player > a.Player) ? -1 : 0));
    return sortedArray;
  }

  function homePlayer1Stats() {
    const filter = homePlayerArray().filter(element => {
      return element.Player === values.homePlayer1
    })
    return filter
  }
  function homePlayer2Stats() {
    const filter = homePlayerArray().filter(element => {
      return element.Player === values.homePlayer2
    })
    return filter
  }

return (
      <>
        <h1>Simulator</h1>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Rules />
        </ErrorBoundary>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Teams
            handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
            home={values.home}
            away={values.away}
          />
        </ErrorBoundary>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Players 
            handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
            homePlayer1={values.homePlayer1}
            homePlayer2={values.homePlayer2}
            awayPlayer1={values.awayPlayer1}
            homePlayerArray={homePlayerArray()}
            awayPlayerArray={awayPlayerArray()}
            homePlayer1Stats={homePlayer1Stats()}
            homePlayer2Stats={homePlayer2Stats()}
          />
        </ErrorBoundary>
```

Part of the team select component

```
<h3>Home Team</h3>
  <select 
    onChange={props.handleInputChange}
    value={props.home}
    name='home'
   >
  <option value={props.home}>
     {props.home}
  </option>
                        
   {countryArray().map((element) => 
   <option key={element} value={element}>
      {element}
   </option>)}
 </select>
```

part of the player select component

```
<td>
  <select 
    onChange={props.handleInputChange}
    value={props.homePlayer1}
    name='homePlayer1'
  >
  <option value={props.homePlayer1>        
     {props.homePlayer1}
  </option>
                                    
  {props.homePlayerArray.map((element) => 
   <option 
     key={element.Player} 
     value={element.Player}
   >
   {element.Player}
   </option>)}
 </select>
</td>
 {props.homePlayer1Stats.map((element) => 
   <td 
     key={element.BatAverage} 
     value={element.BatAverage}
   >
    {element.BatAverage}
  </td>)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass, as argument to the function, the team you want to use as filter:

```js
function homePlayer2Stats(homePlayer) {
  const filter = homePlayerArray().filter(element => {
    return element.Player === homePlayer;
  })
  return filter;
}
```

Now you can reuse the function.

Comment: Thank you. That allows me to use the reuse homePlayerStats function. But I'm still adding a property to the component for each of the players so I've got 11 properties like `homePlayer2Stats = {homePlayerStats(values.homePlayer2)` How do I make it 1 property?

Comment: Instead of declaring 11 homePlayersStats, declare an array of homePlayersStats. Then instead of running the function for each element of the array, use the array method `map` to run a function on all the elements, but in a single statement.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new at all this. Could I trouble you for a quick example?

Comment: @Alccro I would like to help but it's not clear what exactly the code is doing, anyway it should be enough for you to know that in the props of a component you can use the spread syntax `{...anArray}` instead of doing `prop1={anArray[0]} prop2={anArray[1]}` and so on.